# Qt 5.3.1 fails to compile on Mac OS X 10.9.4

Tags: c++, macos, qt5

im trying to compile Qt5 from source on my Mac.
I already did it successfully on my Windows machine.

But on the Mac i get an error during make

[MAKE output](http://pastebin.com/8puL1Ytc)

Has someone an advice for me?

Greetings

Comment: I would assume at least some of those issues are caused by a missing `-framework CoreFoundation` option...

Comment: And where should i add the option?

Comment: Not sure, sorry, but you shouldn't have to add anything if this is building Qt itself. If you cannot make any progress then you might consider installing Qt via http://macports.org (port = `qt5-mac`).